# Plotly animated slider in Python

Tags: python, animation, slider, data-visualization, plotly

I was trying to recreate this example in a Jupyter notebook.

https://plot.ly/python/gapminder-example/

but was getting this error:

```
PlotlyDictKeyError: 'slider' is not allowed in 'layout'

Path To Error: ['layout']['slider']

Valid attributes for 'layout' at path ['layout'] under parents ['figure']:

    ['angularaxis', 'annotations', 'autosize', 'bargap', 'bargroupgap',
    'barmode', 'barnorm', 'boxgap', 'boxgroupgap', 'boxmode', 'calendar',
    'direction', 'dragmode', 'font', 'geo', 'height', 'hiddenlabels',
    'hiddenlabelssrc', 'hidesources', 'hoverlabel', 'hovermode', 'images',
    'legend', 'mapbox', 'margin', 'orientation', 'paper_bgcolor',
    'plot_bgcolor', 'radialaxis', 'scene', 'separators', 'shapes',
    'showlegend', 'sliders', 'smith', 'ternary', 'title', 'titlefont',
    'updatemenus', 'width', 'xaxis', 'yaxis']

Run `<layout-object>.help('attribute')` on any of the above.
'<layout-object>' is the object at ['layout']
```

The animation runs without the slider dict added to layout and the slider is visible and operational, but does not change the graph. When I move the slider it produces the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) undefined
```

Comment: which particular line gave you the error?

Comment: either when I try to create the figure with go.Figure() or when I try to plot the json figure constructed without go.Figure() when I run offline.ilpot(<figure>)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**

I checked the graph you have, I am observing the below error sometimes.

> Uncaught (in promise) undefined

This error might by due to plotly missing an click or other event, but this is internally within the `plotly.js` file, if you go to [Plotly Slider animation](https://plot.ly/python/gapminder-example/) link and to the `slider animation` section, click play and click on the slider while play is running we get this error, even when I click on pause I get this error. But the animation keeps on playing if I press the play again, hence there is no major impact! It's just that an event is not handled properly.

So as in the case of the graph you provided, I can get the animation working fine, eventhough I get the error (`Uncaught (in promise) undefined`) I am still able to play the animation!

You can use either `iplot(fig, validate=False)` or `plot(fig)` to show the graphs in Python with the animation!

**Answer:**

The error is because the `layout` object has a property called `sliders` not `slider`, so wherever you are using `slider` under layout, please change this, also this plot is very complicated and may have other errors also, please share the code, for debugging. But for now this will be my answer.

**Before:**

```
['layout']['slider']
```

**After:**

```
['layout']['sliders']
```

Please replace all the `slider` properties that are related to layout, these need to be changed to `sliders`.

**References:**

I have handled issues related to this particular slider animated Plotly graph. Please refer to them if need, they may help solve your issue!

1. [Plotly Animated Bubble Chart No Data in the Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711830/plotly-animated-bubble-chart-no-data-in-the-plot/45717627#45717627)
2. [Plotly Error Invalid Figure or Data Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699343/plotly-error-invalid-figure-or-data-argument/45708033#45708033)
3. [Plotly Icreate Animations Offline on Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780920/plotly-icreate-animations-offline-on-jupyter-notebook/45825466#45825466)

Comment: The `ctrl+f` part is unnecessary, and probably incorrect too.

Comment: What if the OP is using notebook in a terminal and not something in, eg. a browser?

Comment: @0xc0de ok got it

Answer (score 2):

You are probably hitting this error because of a typo in that notebook. It should be `sliders` instead of `slider`, see the [docs](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-sliders).

The other error too, seems to be caused by this typo. It seems that this code is in an event handler that gets triggered whenever you move the slider.

So below line (and similar ones):

```
figure['layout']['slider']
```

should be corrected to:

```
figure['layout']['sliders']
```

Here is the code for that example:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.grid_objs import Grid, Column
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF 

import pandas as pd
import time

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(url)

table = FF.create_table(dataset.head(10))
py.iplot(table, filename='animations-gapminder-data-preview')


years_from_col = set(dataset['year'])
years_ints = sorted(list(years_from_col))
years = [str(year) for year in years_ints]
years.remove('1957')

# make list of continents
continents = []
for continent in dataset['continent']:
    if continent not in continents: 
        continents.append(continent)

columns = []
# make grid
for year in years:
    for continent in continents:
        dataset_by_year = dataset[dataset['year'] == int(year)]
        dataset_by_year_and_cont = dataset_by_year[dataset_by_year['continent'] == continent]
        for col_name in dataset_by_year_and_cont:
            # each column name is unique
            column_name = '{year}_{continent}_{header}_gapminder_grid'.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header=col_name
            )
            a_column = Column(list(dataset_by_year_and_cont[col_name]), column_name)
            columns.append(a_column)

# upload grid
grid = Grid(columns)
url = py.grid_ops.upload(grid, 'gapminder_grid'+str(time.time()), auto_open=False)

figure = {
    'data': [],
    'layout': {},
    'frames': [],
    'config': {'scrollzoom': True}
}

# fill in most of layout
figure['layout']['xaxis'] = {'range': [30, 85], 'title': 'Life Expectancy', 'gridcolor': '#FFFFFF'}
figure['layout']['yaxis'] = {'title': 'GDP per Capita', 'type': 'log', 'gridcolor': '#FFFFFF'}
figure['layout']['hovermode'] = 'closest'
figure['layout']['plot_bgcolor'] = 'rgb(223, 232, 243)'

figure['layout']['sliders'] = {
    'args': [
        'slider.value', {
            'duration': 400,
            'ease': 'cubic-in-out'
        }
    ],
    'initialValue': '1952',
    'plotlycommand': 'animate',
    'values': years,
    'visible': True
}

figure['layout']['updatemenus'] = [
    {
        'buttons': [
            {
                'args': [None, {'frame': {'duration': 500, 'redraw': False},
                         'fromcurrent': True, 'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'quadratic-in-out'}}],
                'label': 'Play',
                'method': 'animate'
            },
            {
                'args': [[None], {'frame': {'duration': 0, 'redraw': False}, 'mode': 'immediate',
                'transition': {'duration': 0}}],
                'label': 'Pause',
                'method': 'animate'
            }
        ],
        'direction': 'left',
        'pad': {'r': 10, 't': 87},
        'showactive': False,
        'type': 'buttons',
        'x': 0.1,
        'xanchor': 'right',
        'y': 0,
        'yanchor': 'top'
    }
]


sliders_dict = {
    'active': 0,
    'yanchor': 'top',
    'xanchor': 'left',
    'currentvalue': {
        'font': {'size': 20},
        'prefix': 'Year:',
        'visible': True,
        'xanchor': 'right'
    },
    'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'cubic-in-out'},
    'pad': {'b': 10, 't': 50},
    'len': 0.9,
    'x': 0.1,
    'y': 0,
    'steps': []
}

custom_colors = {
    'Asia': 'rgb(171, 99, 250)',
    'Europe': 'rgb(230, 99, 250)',
    'Africa': 'rgb(99, 110, 250)',
    'Americas': 'rgb(25, 211, 243)',
    #'Oceania': 'rgb(9, 255, 255)' 
    'Oceania': 'rgb(50, 170, 255)'
}

col_name_template = '{year}_{continent}_{header}_gapminder_grid'
year = 1952
for continent in continents:
    data_dict = {
        'xsrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='lifeExp'
        )),
        'ysrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='gdpPercap'
        )),
        'mode': 'markers',
        'textsrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='country'
        )),
        'marker': {
            'sizemode': 'area',
            'sizeref': 200000,
            'sizesrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
                 year=year, continent=continent, header='pop'
            )),
            'color': custom_colors[continent]
        },
        'name': continent
    }
    figure['data'].append(data_dict)


for year in years:
    frame = {'data': [], 'name': str(year)}
    for continent in continents:
        data_dict = {
            'xsrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header='lifeExp'
            )),
            'ysrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header='gdpPercap'
            )),
            'mode': 'markers',
            'textsrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header='country'
                )),
            'marker': {
                'sizemode': 'area',
                'sizeref': 200000,
                'sizesrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
                    year=year, continent=continent, header='pop'
                )),
                'color': custom_colors[continent]
            },
            'name': continent
        }
        frame['data'].append(data_dict)

    figure['frames'].append(frame)
    slider_step = {'args': [
        [year],
        {'frame': {'duration': 300, 'redraw': False},
         'mode': 'immediate',
       'transition': {'duration': 300}}
     ],
     'label': year,
     'method': 'animate'}
    sliders_dict['steps'].append(slider_step)

figure['layout']['sliders'] = [sliders_dict]

py.icreate_animations(figure, 'gapminder_example'+str(time.time()))
```

Note: Strange but the code executed successfully for me with the above mentioned typo as well!

[Demo](https://plot.ly/~0x007/7) output.

Answer (score 1):

You need `plotly >= 2.0.0`
try 

`pip install plotly --upgrade`

Comment: That's not it. I have 2.0.15 and I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the documentation is incorrect. But simply replacing all `slider` with `sliders` will still give an error. Therefore, here's a self contained example.

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/empet/365cf202391bf7a58021388fadd52004

Comment: Please bring the content here. Answers must stand alone.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit please start support for embedded jupyter notebook elements. You can always edit and copy-paste.

Comment: Why should I do it? You do it.

Comment: I don't believe that answers need to be standalone. So I shan't. **Act on thy believes and the mass shall follow'th.**

Comment: Why don't you believe this well-documented and self-evident thing?