# Plotly error: Invalid 'figure_or_data' argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, plot, jupyter-notebook, plotly

an animation example from [this plotly tutorial](https://plot.ly/python/animations/1) is not working with Plotly 2.0.12. I put the error output below. Is there any way to solve the problem? I am using plotly on a Jupyter Notebook.

```
PlotlyError: Invalid 'figure_or_data' argument. Plotly will not be 
able to properly parse the resulting JSON. If you want to send this 
'figure_or_data' to Plotly anyway (not recommended), you can set 
'validate=False' as a plot option.  
Here's why you're seeing this error:

'slider' is not allowed in 'layout'

Path To Error: ['layout']['slider']

Valid attributes for 'layout' at path ['layout'] under parents 
['figure']:

['angularaxis', 'annotations', 'autosize', 'bargap', 'bargroupgap',
'barmode', 'barnorm', 'boxgap', 'boxgroupgap', 'boxmode', 'calendar',
'direction', 'dragmode', 'font', 'geo', 'height', 'hiddenlabels',
'hiddenlabelssrc', 'hidesources', 'hoverlabel', 'hovermode', 
'images',
'legend', 'mapbox', 'margin', 'orientation', 'paper_bgcolor',
'plot_bgcolor', 'radialaxis', 'scene', 'separators', 'shapes',
'showlegend', 'sliders', 'smith', 'ternary', 'title', 'titlefont',
'updatemenus', 'width', 'xaxis', 'yaxis']

Run `<layout-object>.help('attribute')` on any of the above.
'<layout-object>' is the object at ['layout']
```

EDIT: Just noticed the link is broken. Here is the full code:

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
from IPython.display import display, HTML

import pandas as pd

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(url)

years = ['1952', '1962', '1967', '1972', '1977', '1982', '1987', '1992', '1997', '2002', '2007']
# make list of continents
continents = []
for continent in dataset['continent']:
    if continent not in continents:
        continents.append(continent)
# make figure
figure = {
    'data': [],
    'layout': {},
    'frames': [],
    'config': {'scrollzoom': True}
}

# fill in most of layout
figure['layout']['xaxis'] = {'range': [30, 85], 'title': 'Life Expectancy'}
figure['layout']['yaxis'] = {'title': 'GDP per Capita', 'type': 'log'}
figure['layout']['hovermode'] = 'closest'
figure['layout']['slider'] = {
    'args': [
        'slider.value', {
            'duration': 400,
            'ease': 'cubic-in-out'
        }
    ],
    'initialValue': '1952',
    'plotlycommand': 'animate',
    'values': years,
    'visible': True
}
figure['layout']['updatemenus'] = [
    {
        'buttons': [
            {
                'args': [None, {'frame': {'duration': 500, 'redraw': False},
                         'fromcurrent': True, 'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'quadratic-in-out'}}],
                'label': 'Play',
                'method': 'animate'
            },
            {
                'args': [[None], {'frame': {'duration': 0, 'redraw': False}, 'mode': 'immediate',
                'transition': {'duration': 0}}],
                'label': 'Pause',
                'method': 'animate'
            }
        ],
        'direction': 'left',
        'pad': {'r': 10, 't': 87},
        'showactive': False,
        'type': 'buttons',
        'x': 0.1,
        'xanchor': 'right',
        'y': 0,
        'yanchor': 'top'
    }
]

sliders_dict = {
    'active': 0,
    'yanchor': 'top',
    'xanchor': 'left',
    'currentvalue': {
        'font': {'size': 20},
        'prefix': 'Year:',
        'visible': True,
        'xanchor': 'right'
    },
    'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'cubic-in-out'},
    'pad': {'b': 10, 't': 50},
    'len': 0.9,
    'x': 0.1,
    'y': 0,
    'steps': []
}

# make data 
year = 1952
for continent in continents:
    dataset_by_year = dataset[dataset['year'] == year]
    dataset_by_year_and_cont = 
dataset_by_year[dataset_by_year['continent'] == continent]

    data_dict = {
        'x': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['lifeExp']),
        'y': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['gdpPercap']),
        'mode': 'markers',
        'text': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['country']),
        'marker': {
            'sizemode': 'area',
            'sizeref': 200000,
            'size': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['pop'])
        },
        'name': continent
    }
    figure['data'].append(data_dict)

# make frames
for year in years:
    frame = {'data': [], 'name': str(year)}
    for continent in continents:
        dataset_by_year = dataset[dataset['year'] == int(year)]
        dataset_by_year_and_cont = 
dataset_by_year[dataset_by_year['continent'] == continent]

        data_dict = {
            'x': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['lifeExp']),
            'y': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['gdpPercap']),
            'mode': 'markers',
            'text': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['country']),
            'marker': {
                'sizemode': 'area',
                'sizeref': 200000,
                'size': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['pop'])
            },
            'name': continent
        }
        frame['data'].append(data_dict)

    figure['frames'].append(frame)
    slider_step = {'args': [
        [year],
        {'frame': {'duration': 300, 'redraw': False},
         'mode': 'immediate',
       'transition': {'duration': 300}}
     ],
     'label': year,
     'method': 'animate'}
    sliders_dict['steps'].append(slider_step)


figure['layout']['sliders'] = [sliders_dict]

iplot(figure)
```

I do not know if I have to downgrade the version (and, in case, to which one) but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I validated your code and found some errors.

1. On Line 29 you should have given

`figure['layout']['sliders']` instead of `figure['layout']['slider']`

2. Plotly offline's iplot function has a separate parameter of inputting config of the plot.

So the below line

```
# make figure
figure = {
    'data': [],
    'layout': {},
    'frames': [],
    'config': {'scrollzoom': True}
}
```

and the line

```
iplot(figure)
```

should actually be written as

```
# make figure
figure = {
    'data': [],
    'layout': {},
    'frames': []
}
config = {'scrollzoom': True}
```

and

```
iplot(figure, config=config)
```

So the final working code should be

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
from IPython.display import display, HTML

import pandas as pd

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(url)

years = ['1952', '1962', '1967', '1972', '1977', '1982', '1987', '1992', '1997', '2002', '2007']
# make list of continents
continents = []
for continent in dataset['continent']:
    if continent not in continents:
        continents.append(continent)
# make figure
figure = {
    'data': [],
    'layout': {},
    'frames': []
}
config = {'scrollzoom': True}

# fill in most of layout
figure['layout']['xaxis'] = {'range': [30, 85], 'title': 'Life Expectancy'}
figure['layout']['yaxis'] = {'title': 'GDP per Capita', 'type': 'log'}
figure['layout']['hovermode'] = 'closest'
figure['layout']['sliders'] = {
    'args': [
        'slider.value', {
            'duration': 400,
            'ease': 'cubic-in-out'
        }
    ],
    'initialValue': '1952',
    'plotlycommand': 'animate',
    'values': years,
    'visible': True
}
figure['layout']['updatemenus'] = [
    {
        'buttons': [
            {
                'args': [None, {'frame': {'duration': 500, 'redraw': False},
                         'fromcurrent': True, 'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'quadratic-in-out'}}],
                'label': 'Play',
                'method': 'animate'
            },
            {
                'args': [[None], {'frame': {'duration': 0, 'redraw': False}, 'mode': 'immediate',
                'transition': {'duration': 0}}],
                'label': 'Pause',
                'method': 'animate'
            }
        ],
        'direction': 'left',
        'pad': {'r': 10, 't': 87},
        'showactive': False,
        'type': 'buttons',
        'x': 0.1,
        'xanchor': 'right',
        'y': 0,
        'yanchor': 'top'
    }
]

sliders_dict = {
    'active': 0,
    'yanchor': 'top',
    'xanchor': 'left',
    'currentvalue': {
        'font': {'size': 20},
        'prefix': 'Year:',
        'visible': True,
        'xanchor': 'right'
    },
    'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'cubic-in-out'},
    'pad': {'b': 10, 't': 50},
    'len': 0.9,
    'x': 0.1,
    'y': 0,
    'steps': []
}

# make data 
year = 1952
for continent in continents:
    dataset_by_year = dataset[dataset['year'] == year]
    dataset_by_year_and_cont=dataset_by_year[dataset_by_year['continent'] == continent]

    data_dict = {
        'x': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['lifeExp']),
        'y': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['gdpPercap']),
        'mode': 'markers',
        'text': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['country']),
        'marker': {
            'sizemode': 'area',
            'sizeref': 200000,
            'size': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['pop'])
        },
        'name': continent
    }
    figure['data'].append(data_dict)

# make frames
for year in years:
    frame = {'data': [], 'name': str(year)}
    for continent in continents:
        dataset_by_year = dataset[dataset['year'] == int(year)]

        dataset_by_year_and_cont=dataset_by_year[dataset_by_year['continent'] == continent]

        data_dict = {
            'x': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['lifeExp']),
            'y': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['gdpPercap']),
            'mode': 'markers',
            'text': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['country']),
            'marker': {
                'sizemode': 'area',
                'sizeref': 200000,
                'size': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont['pop'])
            },
            'name': continent
        }
        frame['data'].append(data_dict)

    figure['frames'].append(frame)
    slider_step = {'args': [
        [year],
        {'frame': {'duration': 300, 'redraw': False},
         'mode': 'immediate',
       'transition': {'duration': 300}}
     ],
     'label': year,
     'method': 'animate'}
    sliders_dict['steps'].append(slider_step)


figure['layout']['sliders'] = [sliders_dict]

iplot(figure, config=config)
```

I hope this helps you resolve your issue, the slider looks great :)

Comment: thanks a lot, you were very helpful! This sample now works perfectly, my new issue is that, when trying to adapt it to some new data, the script draws the "structure" of the plot but with no data in it. The main problem is that no error is raised, so I have no clue about where to find the error. Not sure if I have to open a new question or remain on this one.

Comment: @sato In the above code we can see that the data is obtained from a csv file, I am not sure how your data is going to be, try to do it yourself using the reference link [here](https://plot.ly/python/bubble-charts/), if you are not able to resolve the issue, then raise a new ticket, if you add to this one, it will clutter up the question and will not help other when they use your question for reference.

Comment: thanks Naren, I am working on it since yesterday but no result yet. I raised a new ticket as you suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711830/plotly-animated-bubble-chart-no-data-in-the-plot